# Autofixture and Moq v4

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I installed Autofixture and Moq using Nuget.So I have moq version 4.

When running the following code

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
fixture.CreateAnonymous<ISomething>();
```

the following error shows up

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could
>   not load file or assembly 'Moq,
>   Version=3.1.416.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920'

I've also tried redirected it to the v4,but with no luck.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.416.3" newVersion="4.0.10827.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: See also this ticket: http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4225

Comment: As of [version 2.13.1](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/tags) the necessary assembly binding redirects are now [automatically added to the config file](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/11) when you install the [AutoFixture.AutoMoq](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq) NuGet package.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to redirect an assembly binding in a configuration file, you need to specify the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1` namespace in the [<assemblyBinding> element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx), like in this example:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Moq"
                                  publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920"
                                  culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.416.3"
                                 newVersion="4.0.10827.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It's interesting to point out that library assemblies compiled with an earlier version of .NET (such as [Moq 3](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) and [AutoFixture 2.1](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/)) will automatically be loaded in a process running on .NET 4.0 because of [In-Process Side-by-Side execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx). Here's a quote from MSDN about this:

> If an application is compiled using
>   the .NET Framework 4 runtime but
>   includes a library that was built
>   using an earlier runtime, that library
>   will use the .NET Framework 4 runtime
>   as well. However, if you have an
>   application that was built using an
>   earlier runtime and a library that was
>   built using the .NET Framework 4, you
>   must force your application to also
>   use the .NET Framework 4

**Related resources:**

- [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer did not work for me since I want to use Moq 4 from the same class library (non exe) as **AutoFixture.AutoMoq**. There also seem to be [no plans](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4225) to support Moq 4 from the AutoFixture. I ended up using **AutoFixture.AutoRhinoMocks** as the next most popular choice, which does not conflict with Moq 4.

Comment: What problems are you seeing? I've been using AutoFixture.AutoMoq with Moq 4 for years, without problems.