# Mock object injected via AutoFixture with AutoMoq, unexpected behavior

Tags: moq, autofixture

I've just created my first test using AutoFixture. The SUT has the following constructor.

```
public LoggingService(
    IClientDataProvider clientDataProvider, ... other dependencies...)
```

The test setup has the following code.

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

string ipAddress = "whatever";// fixture.CreateAnonymous<string>();

var clientDataProviderMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IClientDataProvider>>();
clientDataProviderMock.Setup(cdp => cdp.IpAddress).Returns(ipAddress);

LoggingService sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<LoggingService>();
```

Now, when I examine the contents of `sut`, I see that the property `IpAddress` of the injected instance of `IClientDataProvider` returns null instead of "whatever".

What did I do wrong?

---

I copied the service and the necessary interfaces to an empty project and then the mocks worked as expected.

Interfaces that are types of constructor arguments of the service in the real project are defined in 3 separate assemblies that have further dependencies. I had several unexpected "Cannot load assembly" errors on the test start because several further assemblies were needed for those directly referenced assemblies. So it seems to be an assembly loading issue.

However, I tried a variation of the test with manual creation of the SUT instance with mock objects created manually using Moq and the test worked as expected

Comment: Your code looks fine, and I'm not able to reproduce your problem. For me the IpAddress contains "whatever"... Can you try it in an empty project? And what is `AuditHistoryLoggingService` ?

Comment: AuditHistoryLoggingService - read as LoggingService, I just tried to remove the "excessive characters" from the original code.

Comment: The IpAddress property (of type `String`) has the correct value. I have added a breakpoint in LogginService class constructor and examined the `IClientDataProvider` instance. Can you copy paste your `LoggingService` class?

Comment: Since you seem to be running into assembly loading issues, could it be this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505591/autofixture-and-moq-v4

Comment: Mark, thanks for the suggestion but it's something different. As I wrote, the mock instances of dependencies were created and injected into the service but they are not the ones that I set up using Freeze.

Comment: Can you provide a repro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was pretty surprising. When I was creating my unit test project I added the reference to Moq 4.0 first. AutoFixture was added later and since it seems to require Moq 3.1, I copied that dll directly to bin\Debug. However, the corresponding HintPath element in the project file still pointed to the 4.0 dll. As soon as I changed HintPath to point to the place where Moq 3.1 sits the test started to work properly. So Mark was right with his suggestion but the symptoms were quite different.